# Optparse doesn't seem to return ARGV array. Argument Required Error

Tags: ruby, optparse

This is homework and I do not expect you to give me the complete answer.

I'm trying to parse a command line entry such as:

```
 ./apacheReport.rb -u testlog.txt
```

When I enter this:

```
./apacheReport.rb -u testlog.txt
```

I get:

```
Argument required
```

My code is:

```
require_relative 'CommonLog'
require 'optparse'

# puts ARGV.inspect

optparser = OptionParser.new

optU = false
optI = false
optS = false
optH = false

optparser.banner = "apacheReport.rb [options] filename"

        optparser.parse!
rescue => m
        puts m.message
        puts optparser
        exit
end

if ARGV.length < 1
        puts  "Argument required"
        exit
end

userInputFile = ARGV[0]
userInputFile.to_s
file = CommonLog.new(userInputFile)
```

It should parse the leftover portion of the command into `ARGV[0]` then should store it as `userInputFile` and then create a CommonLog object using the file as the constructor. At that point I call the methods that were specified in the command.

It seems that for some reason my ARGV is not being returned. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: You mention using `optparse`, but it doesn't appear in your code. Could you post that as well?

Comment: I apologize as I'm trying to keep as much code out as I can. I added in the optparsing. Keep in mind that some code has still been left out. (Mainly the options)
I have an email in to my teacher, but it has been a few hours so I figured I'd turn to SO to see if they had any answers. Don't want to be late!

Comment: Does the `-u` option take an additional argument? E.g. `opts.on("-u ARGUMENT") ...`?

Comment: None of the options take additional arguments.

Comment: While it's nice that you're stripping out stuff, it's still important that your example code be valid, so you can't strip out require statements or definitions that are necessary.

Comment: I apologize. I will edit the question and post the entire code. Once it has been answered, I will edit out the irrelevant code sections.

Comment: You need to understand how Stack Overflow works. Once you add something to the question, or an answer, Stack Overflow owns it, and applies revision management to it. While you might delete content, once it's in the system it's there to stay, and those of us with sufficient privileges can view the entire revision history. In other words, there ain't no going back.

Comment: While I understand that those with sufficient privileges may see revision history, no students that I know have these privileges. The idea here is to not give the answer away to other students. I think we both understand where we're coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's OptionParser is easy to use, but you have to puzzle through the documentation. Here's a little example that'd be useful for your code:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-u', '--use_this FILE', 'Use this file') { |o| options[:use_this] = o }
end.parse!
```

`options` will contain the flags. In this case, if you pass in `-u foo`, `options[:use_this]` will be `foo`.

Save that and try running it without and with a parameter. Also try running it with just a `-h` flag.

You can [search StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a128421%20optparse) for more answers where I was dealing with OptionParser.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's wrong since you code doesn't seem to be working at the moment. The problem may be that [the `parse!` method](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/OptionParser.html#method-i-parse-21) removes found options from `ARGV`. So when you write:

```
optparser.parse!
```

It removes your two parameters (`-u testlog.txt`) and this code always fails:

```
if ARGV.length < 1
        puts  "Argument required"
        exit
end
```

Instead of looking at `ARGV`, you need to set up `optparser` correctly. Perhaps something like:

```
optparser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "apacheReport.rb [options] filename"
  opts.on("-u", "--u-short-for-this", "Whatever u stands for") do |u|
    optU = u
  end
end
```

Then `optU` will be true only if the user passed `-u` and the filename will be  in `ARGV[0]`.